# Three.JS -- porting a custom vertex shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I'd like to use [this](http://glsl.heroku.com/e#14910.0) shader with three.js.  The vertex shader in this example uses an attribute `surfacePosAttrib` which is set up in the hosting javascript by the following calls I believe:

```
surface.positionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(currentProgram, "surfacePosAttrib");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(surface.positionAttribute);
```

I couldn't find these calls when searching through the `webglrenderer` source for `three.js`, so I believe these buffers are not set up in `three.js`.

Is there a supported way to set these buffers for a custom shader in `three.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this vertex shader in the source code:

```
<script id="surfaceVertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    attribute vec3 position;
    attribute vec2 surfacePosAttrib;
    varying vec2 surfacePosition;

    void main() {

        surfacePosition = surfacePosAttrib;
        gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );

    }

</script>
```

The first line of code you provided the method finds the index bound the attribute `surfacePosAttrib` in the vertex shader inside `current program` and assigns it to `positionAttribute` of `surface` in javascript. The second line is simply enabling it. Javascript buffer names are arbitrary. They have different names in different programs so it's predictable you won't find such buffers in `three.js`.

I'm guessing (not sure though) that almost all the work is done in fragment shader (like most of similar works done by *Iñigo Quílez* can be found in [his shadertoy page](https://www.shadertoy.com/user/iq)) and vertex shader is only providing a surface for fragment shader to draw on.

Below simple example uses custom shaders in `three.js`. It defines a mesh with a 2D plane geometry visible by the camera and defines a custom shader whose vertex shader and fragment shader provided by the user. Note that `projectionMatrix` and `modelViewMatrix` are provided automatically by `three.js` in the vertex shader so you don't need to manually pass them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shading #1</title>
    <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% ;}</style>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>      
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">       
        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
        }           
    </script>

    <script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

        uniform float time;
        uniform vec2 resolution;

        void main()
        {               

            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.0, 0.0 , 1.0);
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});

        var startTime = Date.now();

        //assignings happen here
        //more info on https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types
        var uniforms = {
            time: {
                type: 'f',
                value: 0
            },
            resolution: {
                type: "v2",
                value: new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
            }
        };          
        var myMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vs' ).textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fs' ).textContent
        });

        camera.position.z = 0.40;
        var itemGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( window.innerWidth / (window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight), window.innerHeight / (window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight), 0);
        var itemCube = new THREE.Mesh( itemGeometry, myMaterial );
        scene.add( itemCube );

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


        function render() {

            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            uniforms.time.value = (Date.now() - startTime)/1000;        
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }
        render();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks much for the response.  I am a shader neophyte!  I have this one up and running now, appreciate the input